# I'm having trouble replicating simplest of javascript code using angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd written a very simple widget/snippet. Five stars (using font-awesome) on hover, replace empty star with filled star. On mouse out go back to default no. of star if there is a default value, and on-click change the default value depending on the star clicked (for example click on 4th star would change the value to 4 and so on. Really simple stuff. I can't for the life of me replicate it using angular js...

I know I need to do it using directives and transclusion if I understand it correctly. I'm having so much trouble even getting variable no. of filled and empty stars based on default value....

I'd appreciate it if someone could direct me.. here's the code.

Html stuff

```
<div class="ratingList" rating-widget rate='{{ rating }}' increment="increment()">
<span>Hate it</span>
<span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i></span>
<span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i></span>
<span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i></span>
<span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i></span>
<span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i></span>
<span>love it</span>
```

very basic controller

```
bmApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.rating = 3;

$scope.increment = function(){
$scope.rating = $scope.rating + 1;
}
```

}]);

culprit directive

```
bmApp.directive('ratingWidget', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,

    template: '<div><button ng-click="increment()">Click</button><div class="rating"></div></div>',

    controller:['$scope', '$element', '$transclude', function($scope, $element, $transclude){

        $transclude(function(clone){
            var stars = clone.filter('.star');
            var filledStar = $('<span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></span>');
            var container = $element.find('.rating');
            angular.forEach(stars, function(val, key){
                var star = $(val);
                if(key<$scope.rate)
                {
                    //console.log(key);
                    container.append(filledStar);
                    //star.replaceWith(filledStar);
                    //angular.element(star.children()[0]).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star')

                }else{
                    //console.log(key);
                    container.append(star);
                }       

            });

        });
    }],
    scope:{
        rate:'@',
        increment:'&'
    }
}
```

});

I'm stuck at the very begining, can't show filled stars based on default value... The append is resulting in 3 stars...

Comment: First thing I see is that your DIV should have `rate="rating"` (drop the curlies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways of being able to handle this sort of functionality.

I've updated your example to show the use of the isolate scope and transclusion (for the `increment()` button).

We also bundle the star markup into the `ratingWidget` directive to make it modular and keep it as more of a standalone component.

You can see that because of the `ng-repeat` and `ng-class` directives we don't have to work directly with HTML elements if we don't want to, Angular handles the heavy lifting through data binding.

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hd5DLOpRC3R9EFy316Gl?p=preview

(If you look at the history on that Plunker you will see how I was using jQuery to manipulate the elements/classes directly)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="bmApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <div rating-widget rate="rating" max-rating="maxRating">
                <!--
                This is the content that will be transcluded.

                Transclusion means that this content will linked with
                the parent scope instead of being linked into the
                scope of the `ratingWidget`.

                i.e. the `increment()` function is defined in `MainController` 
                not in the `ratingWidget`.
                -->
            <button ng-click="increment()">Click</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var bmApp = angular.module('bmApp', []);

bmApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.rating = 3;
        $scope.maxRating = 6;

        $scope.increment = function() {
          if ($scope.rating < $scope.maxRating){
            $scope.rating += 1;
          }
        }
    }]);

bmApp.directive('ratingWidget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            rate: '=',
            maxRating: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var classes = {
                empty: 'fa-star-o',
                full: 'fa-star'
            };

            scope.stars = [];
            scope.$watch('maxRating', function(maxRating){
              maxRating = maxRating || 5;
              scope.stars.length = maxRating;
              for (var i = 0, len = scope.stars.length; i < len; i++){
                if (!scope.stars[i]){
                  scope.stars[i] = {
                    cssClass: classes.empty
                  };
                }
              }

              updateRating(scope.rate);
            });

            scope.$watch('rate', function(newRating){
                updateRating(newRating);
            });

            scope.selectRating = function(index){
              // The $index is zero-index but the ratings
              // start at one, so add 1.
              scope.rate = index + 1;
            }

            function updateRating(rating){
                rating = rating || 0;
                for (var i = 0, len = scope.stars.length; i < len; i++){
                    var star = scope.stars[i];
                    if (i < rating){
                      star.cssClass = classes.full;
                    } else {
                      star.cssClass = classes.empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        template:   '<div>' +
                        '<div class="ratingList">' +
                            '<span>Hate it</span>' +
                            '<span class="stars">' +
                              '<span class="star" ng-click="selectRating($index)" ng-repeat="star in stars track by $index"><i class="fa fa-lg" ng-class="star.cssClass"></i></span>' +
                            '</span>' +
                            '<span>love it</span>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div ng-transclude></div' +
                    '</div>'

    }
})
```

---

**Edit:**

@dan-tang

Yes, if you had the button outside the directive but inside `MainController` it would all work as expected and you wouldn't need transclude.

But the point is that the button is inside the directive and calling a method defined on `MainController`. To do that we need to transclude the content so that binds to the parent scope.

Here's a plunker showing this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/x9xZwve9VkwbTGKUGjZJ?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>I am: {{name}}</div>

    <div widget>
        <!-- 
        Without transclusion this will say 'widget', with transclusion this will say 'controller'.
        Transclusion lets us control the scope to which these expressions are bound.
        -->
        <div>I am: {{name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
testApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'controller';
}]);

testApp.directive('widget', function(){
    return {
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.name = 'widget'
        },
        template: '<div>' +
            '<div>I am: {{name}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

I would say that `transclude` in Angular is like a closure in JavaScript - it lets you control the scope to which variables and expressions are bound.

Here's a rough JavaScript analogue of the example above to show some of the similarities between the two concepts:

```
var name = 'controller';
var printCallback = function(){
    console.log('name=' + name);
}

function Widget(printCallback){
    var name = 'widget';

    this.printName = function(){
        console.log('name=' + name);
        printCallback();
    }
}

var widget = new Widget(printCallback);
widget.printName();
// Prints:
// name=widget
// name=controller
```

Comment: Hey man thank you so much. It's so hard to pick up this kind of stuff from documentation. I spent so much time trying to get it right, and looking at your code I'm sure I couldn't have done it without help. Just two questions, in the jquery version, by doing scope.apply, are you pushing the change up to the controller's scope? and lastly the pattern is to have functions change the values and watch them in the directive to do dom manipulations?. Thank you again.

Comment: The `scope.$apply` is used to tell Angular that we have made a change to the scope from outside the Angular framework (i.e. from a jQuery event handler) and that it needs to re-check the scope for binding changes. I don't really understand your second question though, can you please clarify?

Comment: Ah I see. I meant if it's common to have set ups like yours, using functions tied to events to change values and have watchers on those values to update the DOM. Coming from vanilla js/jquery I'd never seen stuff done like that.

Comment: Yes, what I've done is pretty standard (as far as I'm aware). Using `scope.$watch` and `$compile.directive.Attributes.$observer` are the standard ways of managing two-way binding in Angular.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal Pretty nice code! Can I clarify on the usage of transclude? If you had the button outside the rating-widget but still within MainCtrl, wouldn't increment() still work?

Comment: @Sly_cardinal Thank you! Wow, that's really interesting - I didn't expect "name" to refer to the global variable. I did a jsfiddle, and in the case of a self-executing anonymous function, name refers to the name in the outer function due to closure rules; can I ask why in your example name points to the global variable? http://jsfiddle.net/jsB9M/

Answer (score 0):

A ratings system customize level and easy installation , the best I found: https://rating-widget.com/get/rating/